# Cypress does not select a date on calendar

Tags: json, cypress, flatpickr

I want to test a calendar using cypress but it is not possible to select the date I need or any date, the ideal is a dynamic code, where I can enter number of days and it will select the correct number.

I am using this code and I am getting a error saying *'Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined'*

```
  let date = new Date()
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5)
  let futureDay = date.getDate()
  console.log(futureDay)
  let futureMonth = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })
  cy.get('.flatpickr-current-month')
    .invoke('attr', 'flatpickr-monthDropdown-month')
    .then(dateAttribute => {
      if (!dateAttribute.includes(futureMonth)) {
        cy.get('.flatpickr-next-month').click()
      } else {
        cy.get('.dayContainer')
          .contains(futureDay)
          .click()
      }
    })
```

I am able to add unique attributes in the elements if necessary (I tried and still it did not worked).
I was well tried a more simples code as:

```
  cy.get('#inception_date').click()
  cy.get('.flatpickr-days > .dayContainer',)
    .contains('17')
    .click({force: true})
  cy.get('#inception_date')
    .invoke('prop', 'value')
    .should('contain', '2021-07-17')
```

and in this code I get an error of *Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '2021-07-27' to include '2021-07-17'* because it does not select the any date, it continues to be the date of today.

I am attaching 2 images if the DOM, maybe it can help to figure out what is the issue on my code.
[image: imput field]

[image]

Comment: There is no attr `flatpickr-monthDropdown-month` on the element `<div class="flatpickr-current-month">`. Where is 'July' in the screenshot in your DOM? That's the element you want to target.

Comment: @SteveZodiac here is July. `<option class="flatpickr-monthDropdown-month" value="6" tabindex="-1">July</option>`

Comment: No, that's just one of the options that shows when you open the dropdown.

Comment: I can see the select date only in the prop, but not in the DOM.. the only place it shows a bit different is here `<span class="flatpickr-day selected" aria-label="July 21, 2021" tabindex="-1">21</span>`. if you select a day only the select appears in front of the class attribute

Comment: Yeah, the `select` holds the `value` of the selected option and displays it's text (all internal to the select, not visible in the DOM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the examples for flatPickrJS, you want

```js
let date = new Date()                        // July 28 
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5)             // Aug 2
let futureDay = date.getDate()               // get 2 (integer)
let futureMonth = date.getMonth()            // gets 6 (integer) for July

cy.get('.flatpickr-current-month select')    // <select> is nested inside
  .invoke('val')                             // this is the currently selected month
  .then(dateAttribute => {                   // this is "6" for July (months are 0-based)

    if (+dateAttribute !== futureMonth) {    // +dateAttribute converts string to integer
      cy.get('.flatpickr-next-month').click()  // change month to Aug
    }

    cy.get('.dayContainer')                    // selects Aug 2
      .contains(new RegExp(`^${futureDay}$`))  // which is July 28
      .click()                                 // plus 5 days
  })

cy.get('input.flatpickr')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', '2021-08-02')                  // passes
```

**Summary of changes**

- get the numeric futureMonth not the string month name.
- get the value of the current month from the `<select>` using `.invoke('val')`.
- compare current month to futureMonth, if not the same click next-month button.
- take the day container click out of `} else {`, because you always need to select the day.

---

**NOTE**

Thanks to @SyedMuhammadAwais for finding a bug in the day selection code.

Using `.contains(futureDay)` does a partial match, but the calendar sometimes shows some days from the previous month, but they are disabled (not clickable).

So, if futureDay === 6 and the 26th of the previous month is showing, this disabled day will be selected and fail the test.

The solution is to use an exact text match, which can be done with a regex like this

```js
.contains(new RegExp(`^${futureDay}$`))
```

Comment: would it work it another month? Need to have the option to select any month.

Comment: I got error _Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.invoke() errored because the property: value does not exist on your subject.

cy.invoke() waited for the specified property value to exist, but it never did._

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still it does not work. I dont get any errors, but the cy.contaibs, find the current day I want, but it still select the Today day. 
`<span class="flatpickr-day today selected" aria-label="July 28, 2021" aria-current="date" tabindex="-1">28</span>` is how appears in the DOM

`else {
        cy.get('.flatpickr-days')
          .contains(futureDay)
          .click({ force: true })`

Comment: It's because you have an invalid logic in the if/else structure. When the month changes you do not pick any day. You should remove the else part and always pick the day.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code with some amendments in code of @Steve Zodiac

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 8)
let futureDay = date.getDate()
let futureMonth = date.getMonth()
cy.log(futureDay)               // get 6 (integer)
cy.log(futureMonth)            // gets 7 (integer) for August
cy.get('input[placeholder="Day"]').click({force:true})
cy.wait(5000)
cy.get('.flatpickr-current-month > select > option').eq(0)    
  .invoke('val')                             // this is the currently 
   selected month
  .then(dateAttribute => {                   // this is "6" for July 
                                               (months are 0-based)
    if (+dateAttribute !== futureMonth) {    // +dateAttribute converts string to integer
      cy.get('.flatpickr-next-month').click({force: true}
    }

    cy.get('.dayContainer')                    // selects Aug 6
      .contains(new RegExp(futureDay, "g"))
      .click({force:true})                                 // plus 8 days
  })
```

Comment: `cy.get('.flatpickr-current-month > select > option').eq(0)` will always get January.

Comment: And `cy.wait(5000)` is not necessary.

Comment: And `.contains(new RegExp(futureDay, "g"))` has the same problem as `.contains(futureDay)`, it can possibly match the wrong day.

Comment: One more, if you are using `.click({force: true})` then it's likely the element is hidden or disabled (therefore the wrong element). You don't need to force in flatpickr, it's an anti-pattern to do so.

Comment: cy.get('.flatpickr-current-month > select > option').eq(0) is getting the current month . previous months are not being shown in the DOM.

Comment: Nope, that only applies when `minDate: "today"` option is set, but will not work if you configure to choose past dates. The way that works for any configuration is to take the value of the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for the datepicker "previous days" exist or not issue when testing with Cypress.

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
    'selectDate',
    (picker, date) => {
        
        let pickerDate = date.split('-')
        let year = pickerDate[0]
        let month = pickerDate[1]
        let day = pickerDate[2]

        cy.get(picker).click()

        cy.get('.numInput.cur-year').eq(0).filter(':visible').clear().type(year)
        let selectedMonth = parseInt(month, 10)
    
        cy.get('.flatpickr-monthDropdown-months')
            .eq(0)
            .select(selectedMonth - 1)

        //set day -> count how many 'prevMonthDay' is int the calendarMonth and add the number to the day we wants
        //filtering here for get the correct day
        // if there is any prev day !!
        cy.get('.flatpickr-rContainer')
            .then($body => {
                if ($body.find('.flatpickr-day.prevMonthDay').length) {
                    return ['.flatpickr-day.prevMonthDay', ($body.find('.flatpickr-day.prevMonthDay').length).toString()];
                }else{
                    return ['.flatpickr-day', '0'];
                }
            })
            .then(selector => {
                if(selector[0] === '.flatpickr-day.prevMonthDay'){
                    cy.log('prev days')
                    cy.get(`.dayContainer span:nth-child(${parseInt(day, 10) + parseInt(selector[1])})`)
                        .eq(0)
                        .click()
                }else{
                    cy.log('no prev days')
                    cy.get(`.dayContainer span:nth-child(${parseInt(day, 10)})`)
                        .eq(0)
                        .click()
                }
            });
    }
)
```